# Getting error "1366 Incorrect integer value: '1'" when importing file

Tags: mysql, powershell, inline-editing

I'm trying to inline upload data stored in UTF-8 text files, and I have two problems. Firstly, there's currently no primary key set on this table, and it's not set to auto-increment or forced to be null at this point; the first column will be the intended primary key once all the data is loaded, and foreign keys will be added at that point.

I received the following error:

> 25 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1366 Incorrect integer value: '1' for column 'idtable_file' at row 1 Records: 25  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1

when trying to run this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path' INTO TABLE sandr.table_file 
columns terminated by ','   
LINES terminated by '\n'
(idtable_file, owner_id, folder_id, @modified_date, @created_date, size, filename)
SET modified_date = STR_TO_DATE(@modified_date,'%d/%m/%Y %T'),
    created_date = STR_TO_DATE(@created_date,'%d/%m/%Y %T')
```

on this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_file` (
  `idtable_file` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `folder_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I'm doing something wrong but I've just started with MySQL so I'm stabbing in the dark a fair bit, any ideas on that?  Also, though the above SQL query works fine in PowerShell when it's just this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path' INTO TABLE sandr.table_file 
columns terminated by ','   
LINES terminated by '\n'
```

It bombs out with:

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Fatal error encountered during command execution."

if I add the adjustment to the date fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 25 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1366 Incorrect integer value: '1' for column 'idtable_file' at row 1 Records: 25 Deleted: 0 Skipped: 0 Warnings: 1

I also have encountered this error. The thing to note is that

- **the error is apparently absurd** (it seems to say that "1", which is an integer, is an incorrect integer value), and
- it happens on **the very first column of the very first row** and **only there**.

If these two conditions hold, then in all probability the culprit is a hidden three-byte sequence which is smack at the beginning of the SQL file you're trying to load (it's called an *UTF8 Byte-Order Mark*).

In some cases the sequence is escaped in the error message and is shown recognizably, for example [in this bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4960). In other cases it is sent to the user as part of a value:

```
Incorrect integer value: '###1'  ...
```

but the terminal "eats" the BOM and what you see is the (now absurd) error

```
Incorrect integer value: '1' ...
```

To solve the problem, you need to open the file to be imported in some editor capable of removing the byte order mark (e.g. Notepad++).

Comment: I just need to figure out what's causing powershell to throw an exception, and that's a weeks worth of effort on my part pretty much done.  Would you suggest me raising that as a separate question?

Comment: I've got a query and non query function,  I'll paste in the non query function when I get back in the office,  about 30 minutes.  It's probably something obvious or a syntax issue...

Comment: I run the following function:

Comment: function Exec-NonQuery([string]$query)  
{  
  $Connection.open()  
  $command = $connection.CreateCommand()    $command.CommandText = $query   
  $RowsInserted = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()  
  $command.Dispose()   
  $Connection.Close()   
  if ($RowsInserted)   
    {   
    return $RowInserted   
    } 
    else  
    {  
    return $query  
    }  
  }

Comment: then just :     $SqlQuery = @"
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE $path INTO TABLE sandr.table_file 
columns terminated by ','  
LINES terminated by '\r\n'

"@
    }

Exec-NonQuery  $SqlQuery

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to resolve the add  a line break problem in this window :P   I should probably just pack up the pc :P