# sql Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value

Tags: mysql, csv, import

i'm trying to import a csv file into MySQL under CentOS.
The csv file comes from a conversion of excel under Windows. Here it is:

> 1,Colombo

Then I create a table with the command:

```
create table testcity2 (id Integer, name_eng varchar(100), primary key(id)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8;
```

After that I try to import it:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '~/citytmp.csv' INTO TABLE testcity2 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

For now everything seems fine.

However, when I try to import csv file containing multiple lines, everything is mess up. I mean when I `select * from testcity2`, I get messy codes.

Here is the warning that I get:

> Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '﻿1' for column 'id' at row
>   1

Comment: Since the source file was made in windows, did you try using '\r\n' as line terminator?

Comment: @DrIvol  yes I did.

Comment: Then I wouldn't know how to fix this. It seems that there are a lot of other related questions regarding the 1366 error, maybe you can find a solution there.

Comment: @DrIvol   oh I got it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546890/getting-error-1366-incorrect-integer-value-1-when-importing-file