# PHP mySQL INSERT Statement using variables with Integer value

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to import a (simple) CSV file into a MySQL table.

I can connect fine and I have tested the statement with some dummy data and verfied that it writes to the table correctly.  My problem comes in when I attempt to use variables in the statement.  Example:

```
$sql = "INSERT into `link_titles` (`title_id`, `title`, `description`) VALUES ('$data[0]', '$data[1]', '$data[2]')";
$conn->exec($sql);
```

This generates the error:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect
>       integer value: '5' for column 'title_id' at row 1

So, I assume that that something is wrong with the first variable and I remove the single quotes from the first variable (`$data[0]`):

```
$sql = "INSERT into `link_titles` (`title_id`, `title`, `description`) VALUES ($data[0], '$data[1]', '$data[2]')";
$conn->exec($sql);
```

However, if I **manually** enter in the integer '5' (the value that's being read) it works.

```
$sql = "INSERT into `link_titles` (`title_id`, `title`, `description`) VALUES (5, '$data[1]', '$data[2]')";
$conn->exec($sql);
```

I've researched converting a string to an integer (PHP is *supposed* to handle this), but when I attempt to do so, it converts to a 0

```
echo (int)$data[0];   <------  Results in 0
```

I'm at a loss.  A point in the right direction would we awesome

#### Update #1:

This is the mySQL command I used to create the `link_titles` table:

```
CREATE TABLE link_titles( id int not null auto_increment primary key, title_id int(10) unsigned  not null, title varchar(120) default null, description  varchar(512) default null, FOREIGN KEY fk_id(title_id) REFERENCES links(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT );
```

Resulting in this table:

```
desc link_titles;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| title       | varchar(120)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(512)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

#### Update #2

Taking the advice from the comments and the answer provided by @Ligemar, I modified my PHP code as follows:

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT into link_titles (title_id, title, description)
                      VALUES (:tid, :title, :description)");

$sql->bindParam(':tid', $tid);
$sql->bindParam(':title', $title);
$sql->bindParam(':description', $description);

//while loop to parse CSV file excluded for brevity

$tid = $data[0];
$title = $data[1];
$description = $data[2];

$sql->execute();
```

As before, I still get the same error:

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '5' for column 'title_id' at row 1
```

Comment: Ok, first of all, your query is vulnerable to Sql Injection....however, if you want to continue on that path, you need to concatenate the value, like: `$sql = "INSERT into link_titles (title_id, title, description) VALUES (".$data[0].", '$data[1]', '$data[2]')";`...if you want to do things right, you should go for prepared statements http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Just curious, have you considered LOAD DATA INFILE for this?

Comment: @Hackerman - thanks for the info.  Just so you know, this isn't something I'm doing for public consumption...it's merely to import data into a table and learn some PHP while at it.  Right after typing the question, I continued my research and found this on [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).  I attempted it and got the same results.

Comment: @Don'tPanic - Yes.  I considered it but went with PHP so I can get more experience on it (I'm not a dev).  I may end up that way, but I'd like to learn how solve this issue for future use.

Comment: Can you show your create table statememt please?

Comment: @Bleach - I don't have that anymore (did it directly in mySQL).  I can provide you with a description of the table (`desc link_titles;`) if that will work

Comment: Just curious if your title_is is auto_increment.

Comment: @Bleach no, it's not.  Actually, I found my notes.  See edit.

Comment: Look at your table. statement. It is auto incremented.

Comment: Nevermind. I misread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### UTF-8 Byte-Order-Mark (BOM)

After much consternation leading to copious amounts of research, I was able to figure out the issue:  **UTF-8 Byte-Ordered-Mark (BOM) at the beginning of the file.**<sup>1</sup>

```
$ file test.csv
test.csv: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with very long lines, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

After fixing the file, I was able to run the code with no problem resulting in successfully importing the file.

```
file test-nobom.csv
test-nobom.csv: UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

#### Remove the BOM from the file

Apparently, Windows OSs (though this was done in Excel for Mac) adds this bogus character to the front of these text files.  I found a number of ways to fix it

- Windows GUI editor:  ([Notepad ++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/))
- Using `sed`<sup>2</sup>:

  `sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' < foo-withBOM > foo-withoutBOM.txt`
- Using `dos2unix` command <sup>3</sup>
- Using the `tail` command <sup>4</sup>

  `tail -c +4 foo-withBOM.txt > foo-withoutBOM.txt`

---

<sup>1</sup> [Getting error “1366 Incorrect integer value: '1'” when importing file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31547109/4703819)

<sup>2</sup> https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381263/107777

<sup>3</sup> https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381237/107777

<sup>4</sup> https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381231/107777

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're coding this from PDO because you use the `->exec` method.

Please use parameters:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Especially if you are just starting out with PHP, doing SQL injection will make you a poor developer and creates bad habits. Using a prepared SQL statement is the correct way to do it because the queries will be safe from injection attacks, you can change the DB backend easier, commit transactions with better debugging, and can provide caching and other things "sever-side".

Try something like this:

```
<?php

$sql = 'INSERT into `link_titles` (`title_id`, `title`, `description`) 
        VALUES (:first, :second, :somethingelse)';

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$result = $sth->execute(
    [
     ':first' => $data[0], 
     ':second' => $data[1], 
     ':somethingelse' => $data[2]
    ]
);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Though this wasn't the solution (it was a BOM issue), I do appreciate the coding technique suggestion and I have already changed my code using this technique.

Comment: Yeah PHP isn't the best with integer types ;-) best of luck to ya @Allan I would be curious if a mysql function could have solved your problem as well.

Comment: Trying to import them directly through mySQL is what got me researching - it also gave me an integer error (taking PHP out of the equation).

Answer (score -1):

### its var $data[0] is not an integer

```
try this function ==> intval($data[0]);
```

### http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.intval.php

Comment: Same as if I used `(int)$data[0];` the values comes out to `0` (zero)

Comment: $ data [0] is a string.
because you do not change your column in the title_id database int (10) to title_id varchar ()