# When I try insert in sql a negative number from a pandas colums the console show me the error Incorrect decimal value

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas

I cant insert a negative number in sql database beacuse it is a negative, I already change the type of data from int to decimal and still not working.

The firts negative number in dataframe is the error, the '-5'

```
    Pos                  Team  Pld   W   D   L  GF  GA   GD  Pts
0     1          Flamengo (C)   38  21   8   9  68  48  +20   71
1     2         Internacional   38  20  10   8  61  35  +26   70
2     3      Atlético Mineiro   38  20   8  10  64  45  +19   68
3     4             São Paulo   38  18  12   8  59  41  +18   66
4     5            Fluminense   38  18  10  10  55  42  +13   64
5     6                Grêmio   38  14  17   7  53  40  +13   59
6     7             Palmeiras   38  15  13  10  51  37  +14   58
7     8                Santos   38  14  12  12  52  51   +1   54
8     9  Athletico Paranaense   38  15   8  15  38  36   +2   53
9    10   Red Bull Bragantino   38  13  14  11  50  40  +10   53
10   11                 Ceará   38  14  10  14  54  51   +3   52
11   12           Corinthians   38  13  12  13  45  45    0   51
12   13   Atlético Goianiense   38  12  14  12  40  45   −5   50
13   14                 Bahia   38  12   8  18  48  59  −11   44
14   15                 Sport   38  12   6  20  31  50  −19   42
15   16             Fortaleza   38  10  11  17  34  44  −10   41
16   17     Vasco da Gama (R)   38  10  11  17  37  56  −19   41
17   18             Goiás (R)   38   9  10  19  41  63  −22   37
18   19          Coritiba (R)   38   7  10  21  31  54  −23   31
19   20          Botafogo (R)   38   5  12  21  32  62  −30   27

queryCreateTable = """CREATE TABLE FOOTBALL(
Pos int(2) not null,
Team varchar(255) not null,
J int(2) not null,
V int(2) not null,
E int(2) not null,
D int(2) not null,
GP int(2) not null,
GC int(2) not null,
SG decimal(3) not null,
Pts int(2) not null)"""

cursor.execute(queryCreateTable)

mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO football (Pos, Team, J, V, E, D, GP, GC, SG, Pts) 
                           VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) """

cursor.executemany(mySql_insert_query, tuples_list)
connection.commit()
```

and the ouput is `1366 (HY000): Incorrect decimal value: '−5' for column 'GD' at row 13`

Comment: what is the output of `type(df.loc[12,'GD'])`

Comment: Object. I already try to convert to int and float, but now work too

Comment: ohh so try `df['GD']=pd.to_numeric(df['GD'],errors='coerce')`

Comment: Why does the error say GD when you have no GD column in your create table?

Comment: doesnt work, changed all negative number into "NaN'

Comment: see if this question gives you any insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546890/getting-error-1366-incorrect-integer-value-1-when-importing-file

Comment: In the table you copied into the question, the minus signs are not ordinary minuses, they're Unicode U+2212 MINUS SIGN. Try changing those to "normal" minus signs. (So probably a similar problem to the one Riley Eaton linked to, but not quite the same.)